# show/hide dropdown menu on click, hide on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want to make a div that will show when clicked on a link, and also close when clicked on that same link.  That div also has to fade out when a user scrolls down, and disappear until the user clicks on the same link again. HTML:

```js
var slidesource = document.getElementById('panel');

document.getElementById('dropnavbutton').onclick = function() {
  slidesource.className = slidesource.className ? '' : 'fade';
}
```

```css
.paneldrop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 48.2%;
  transition: 0.3s linear 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.paneldrop li {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s linear 0s;
}

.manjipaneldrop {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: 0.3s linear 0s;
}

div#panel {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

div#panel.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.dropnav {
  color: #3a3a57;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #61b9f6;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a id="dropnavbutton" class="linknav" onclick="dropdownmenu()">Explore</a>
  <div class="paneldrop" id="panel">
    <div class="littlepaneldrop">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="dropnav" href="#">Culture</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropnav" href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropnav" href="#">Nature</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS (Fade out/in doesn't work, unlike basic show/hide) If anybody has any idea how to approach this problem: hide menu when scrolling down and it stays hidden until the user clicks on the link again.

Thank you

Comment: Could you create a working demo (snippet, jsfiddle, codepen) thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, (since you are asking for an approach) using jQuery for user interactions like this, is the smartest thing to do almost all the time.

You can use [jQuery's fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) method out of the box like this.

```
$("#dropnavbutton").click( function (){
    $(".paneldrop").fadeToggle();
});
```

To make the panel fadeout when scrolling,

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e){ 
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 200){
        $(".paneldrop").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: And also `$(window).on('scroll', function(e){ $(".paneldrop").fadeOut(); })`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
If i remove this jquery and use 3.2.1, parallax effect stops working.

Comment: For older jQuery use `$(window).scroll(function(e){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a [scroll listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) to your page.

Here's some pseudo code logic:

```
ScrollListenerOnWindow() { // Fires whenever the page is scrolled
    if (panelDrop is visible) {
        // Make it not visible
    }
}
```

And just keep your current show/hide click logic as is.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("body").addEventListener("scroll", 
    dropscroll);
    var x = document.getElementById("panel");
    function dropscroll() {
        if(x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display == "none";
         }
    }`
Still doesn't give the results needed